# Alternative to defining aliases in /etc/hosts?

Tags: unix, hosts

Is it possible, without editing the `/etc/hosts` file, tell my computer redirect to `127.0.0.1` every time I visit `domain1.com` or `domain1.com` through the web browser as well as when I request the content of the same pages through `curl`?

Answer (score 2):

Run a DNS server/resolver on your machine, configure to forward every query that it can't resolve to the DNS resolvers upstream and set /etc/resolv.conf to direct all queries to the locally running resolver.

Then in the local resolver add entries for the domains you want to blackhole toward localhost.

There are several of options to chose from. The currently most popular caching resolver is [unbound](https://www.unbound.net/), but you can also use [dnscache](https://cr.yp.to/djbdns/dnscache.html) for it.

Comment: nice. can you please provide an example with `unbound`?