# How to properly configure Unbound DNS Resolver?

Tags: dns

What short of configurations should I make in order to tell my computer redirect to `127.0.0.1` every time I visit `domain1.com` or `www.domain1.com` through the web browser as well as when I request the content of those pages through `curl`?

- 1st step: sudo apt-get install unbound
- 2nd step: ???

Comment: Follow-on question from [Alternative to defining aliases in /etc/hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438487/alternative-to-defining-aliases-in-etc-hosts).

Answer (score 1):

Try this as step 1:

```
echo '127.0.0.1 domain1.com www.domain1.com' | sudo tee --append /etc/hosts
```